# Unable to fetch ID using Postgres Stored Function - Bad value for type int

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, stored-functions

I am trying to get location information from the schema Location. 
Postgres version is `9.3.15` and maven jar used is `9.4-1200-jdbc4` ubuntu 14.04 LTS. For connection pooling, I am using `mchange` version `0.9.5.2`.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type int : -,24.7477464699999992,32.7477464700000027,232328,xxxx,xxxxx,xxxx,"xxxx",India,landmark
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.toInt(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2962)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getInt(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2145)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getInt(NewProxyResultSet.java:425)
    at com.creo.hike.direct.storage.jdbc.service.LocationService.getLocation(LocationService.java:74)
    at com.creo.hike.direct.storage.jdbc.service.LocationService.getLocation(LocationService.java:66)
    at com.creo.hike.direct.testapp.App.testLocationService(App.java:38)
    at com.creo.hike.direct.testapp.App.main(App.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Location Schema.

```
CREATE TABLE Location (
    LocationId  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Latitude    DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    Longitude   DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    Pincode     INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    InnerAddress TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown',
    Locality     TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown',
    City         TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown',
    State        TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown',
    Country      TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown',
    Landmark     TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown'
);
```

Insertion of Location is working good, but when trying to fetch Location with generated `LocationId`, it is failed using stored function .
Stored procedure - Getting location by id `gets_location_by_id`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gets_location_by_id(
    localId INTEGER
 ) RETURNS Location AS $$
  DECLARE
     row Location%ROWTYPE;
  BEGIN
     SELECT * INTO row
     FROM Location
         WHERE LocationId = localId;
     RETURN row;
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Please let me know, if I am missing something here. Java code to get location by id is

```
String sql = "SELECT gets_location_by_id(?)";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setInt(1, locationId);
ResultSet resultSet  = statement.executeQuery();
 location = new Location(
                resultSet.getInt(1),
                resultSet.getDouble(2),
                resultSet.getDouble(3),
                resultSet.getInt(4),
                resultSet.getString(5),
                resultSet.getString(6),
                resultSet.getString(7),
                resultSet.getString(8),
                resultSet.getString(9),
                resultSet.getString(10));
```

Comment: Are you sure that SELECT * is returning LocationId, Latitude , Longitude, Pincode, ... into row in this exact order?

Comment: Yes. It was returning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a row from a table which is of the data type that is specifically made for every relation. So rather than getting 10 values, you get 1 composite value. You can solve this quite easily by using the function as a row source in your query:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM gets_location_by_id(?)";
```

You could then also simplify your function as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION gets_location_by_id(localId INTEGER) RETURNS SETOF Location AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM Location WHERE LocationId = localId;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```